# WebStorm support for Polymer library

Tags: javascript, polymer, webstorm

I would like to know how to add support for Polymer elements in WebStorm.

Currently the editor shows that the HTML tags are unknown and the properties cannot be shown with auto-complete. I have attached an example with "paper-item" from Polymer 3.0

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module">
        import '@polymer/paper-item/paper-item.js';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <paper-item>Item</paper-item>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script type="module">` does not work without `src`. `modules` must not be inline Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer 3 web components are not yet supported. Please vote for [WEB-42420](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42420) and linked tickets

Comment: Is it supposed to be solved with the web-types, the JSON standard to document web component libraries? There is already a project from Jetbrains: [https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types](https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types) and it was first mentioned in one of Webstorm releases: [https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/07/webstorm-2019-2-eap-6/#vue](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/07/webstorm-2019-2-eap-6/#vue). So far I have seen web-types for Vue components.

Comment: yes, it will likely work with any kind of web components when [WEB-39620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39620) is implemented. Currently web-types are only supported for Vue.js